# How to implement return in swapping algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, swap

I am writing code to implement a swap that places all elements at even indexes to be less than or equal to their neighbors and all elements at odd indexes to be greater than or equal to their neighbors. I need to have a return statement at the end of my rearrange method, but since there is no if else statement I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Problem3 {

public static boolean rearrange(int[] A)
{
    /*
Input: an array, A, of n sorted integers (positive, negative, or 0) that 
A[0] <= A[1] <= A[2] <=…A[n-2] <= A[n-1]

Output: re-arrange elements in A such that: 
Element at even position (i.e., A[0], A[2]) are less than or equal to both of its neighbors
Element at odd position (i.e., A[1], A[3]) are greater than or equal to both of its neighbors

A[0] <= A[1] >= A[2] <= A[3] >= A[4] <= A[5]…

Design an algorithm that solves this problem in O(n) time.

     */
    for (int i=1; i<A.length-1;){
        swap(A,A[i],A[i+1]);
    }

}

public static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j){
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[i+1];
    A[i+1] = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {13, 20, 45, 69, 78, 100, 127, 155};

    System.out.println("Before:");

    for(int i=0; i < A.length; i++){

        System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
    }

    rearrange(A);

    System.out.println("After:");

    for(int i=0; i < A.length; i++){

        System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
    }



}

}
```

Comment: a return of a boolean which depends on what?

Comment: You need to figure out what the method should return yourself (or ask whomever gave you the assignment), we can't tell you that.

Comment: I'm not sure, I am required to return a Boolean in some way, but my code doesn't necessarily require it I don't think. Maybe I should add an if else statement returning true or false based on if the element reached the end of the array or not? even though this is already taken care of in the for loop head.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code?

Comment: @VladBochenin yes, but it obviously will not run without a return value, but if this was not needed it would work.

Comment: @Katie Even if you put `return true` in `rearrange` it will fail with ArrayIndexOfBoundException in the first swap operation. Also, you don't use `j` inside of `swap` and you don't increment `i` in your loop. This is just from the top. Should `rearrange` return just boolean or it can return something else, resulting array for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, you can return `false` just if method is not able to rearrange array. It could be for example if some of contracts are violated. In your task I see two contracts:

- input should not be `null`
- input array should be sorted.

In this case, your method can looks like:

```
public static boolean rearrange(int[] A) {
    if (A == null || !isSorted(A)) {
        return false;
     }

     .... rearranging algorithm here
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think using loop for swapping Array is pretty expensive along with extra pointer variable J, because if you are using loop then it will raise complexity to 2N.

**loop will execute like ((N+1)+N), which means 2N.**

I believe putting money with `recursion` will be a favorable, below I am sharing a same stuff which I tried with recursion. However return should be independent from base call, validation can be done it self before calling actual logic of working function.

```
public class Problem3 {

    /*
     * Input: an array, A, of n sorted integers (positive, negative, or 0) that
     * A[0] <= A[1] <= A[2] <=…A[n-2] <= A[n-1]
     * 
     * Output: re-arrange elements in A such that: Element at even position
     * (i.e., A[0], A[2]) are less than or equal to both of its neighbors
     * Element at odd position (i.e., A[1], A[3]) are greater than or equal to
     * both of its neighbors
     * 
     * A[0] <= A[1] >= A[2] <= A[3] >= A[4] <= A[5]…
     * 
     * Design an algorithm that solves this problem in O(n) time.
     * 
     */
    public static int[] swap(int[] A, int i) {
        if (i < A.length - 1) {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[i + 1];
            A[i + 1] = temp;
            i = i + 1;
            swap(A, i);
        }
        return A;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] A = { 13, 20, 45, 69, 78, 100, 127, 155 };

        System.out.println("Before:");

        for (int i : A) {

            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("\nAfter:");

        for (int i : swap(A, 0)) {

            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Recursion is fine, in case if you have small arrays. In another case, you can get StackOverflowException.

Comment: Your code doesn't solve the problem: For input `13, 20, 45, 69, 78, 100, 127, 155 ` it returns `20 45 69 78 100 127 155 13 `

Comment: will you please specify, what other cases with big array you will receive StackOverFlowException. Because StackOverFlowException occur if your recursion is not handle with correctly and in above code we will put it in recursion only if index in the limit so I will not cause StackOverFlowException.

Comment: And what is the expected out put here, if you swap complete array this will be your output. If this is not right then please share expected output.

Comment: from Javadoc: StackOverflowError Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply. Stack size depends from `-Xss` property, on my machine I can reach it with 12000 elements in array `swap(new int[12000], 0)`

Comment: expected output described in the task: A[0] <= A[1] >= A[2] <= A[3] >= A[4] <= A[5] .....